# Proving that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \sin(x)\cos(\tfrac1x) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Prove that: $$\lim_{x\to 0} \sin(x)\cos(\tfrac1x) = 0$$

I am completely confused in knowing where to begin problems like this.

I have the beginning: 
For all $\epsilon > 0$ choose $\delta = ?$...
When $|x-0|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-0| = |\sin(x)\cos(1/x)-0| \quad \ldots \quad < \epsilon$.

I need step by step help because I am completely lost in understanding how to complete this type of problem.

Comment: For some basic information about writing maths at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Comment: My own approach would be to observe that $\lim_{x\to 0}\sin x$ is zero and that $\cos(1/x)$ is bounded on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: This proof is almost identical to the one I just helped you through [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/431027/finding-limits-using-the-definition).  Please, consider going to your instructor for help understanding the definition!

Answer (score 4):

This is quite straightforward:

- $|\sin(x) \cdot \cos(1/x)| = |\sin(x)|\cdot |\cos(1/x)|\le |\sin(x)|$ for all $x \ne 0$.
- $|\sin(x)|$ tends to zero as $x$ tends to zero.
- By the [Sandwich Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SqueezingTheorem.html), $|\sin(x) \cdot \cos(1/x)|$ tends to zero as $x$ tends to zero.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed an easy question. But for beginners,  it may not be so, especially we require to show it in $\epsilon-\delta$ language. Anyway, here it is:

First note that $|\sin (x)|\leq |x|$, this plainly gives $\lim_\limits{x\rightarrow 0}\sin (x)=0$.

Now, for any given $\epsilon>0$, choose $\delta=\epsilon$. Then note  $|\cos(1/x)|\leq 1$,   one  has
$$
|\sin(x)\cos(1/x)|\leq |x|<\delta=\epsilon, \quad \text{whenever} \quad  0<|x|<\delta,
$$
showing $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\sin (x)\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=0.$$

Comment: For future reference, I suggest that you read [this FAQ entry](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/114/43351) regarding answering homework questions.

Comment: To elaborate, for a small enough δ, we have $|\sin(u)|≤|u| – $

Answer (score 0):

It’s quite easy, first of all,

$\sin(x)\cos\left(\dfrac1x\right)=\dfrac12\left[\sin\left(x +\dfrac1x\right) +\sin\left(x -\dfrac1x\right)\right]$

expand the above using taylor's series    $\sin(x)=x-\dfrac{x^3}{3!} +\dfrac{x^5}{5!}+\ldots$

on simplifying for some degrees we see that all $\;\dfrac1x ,\dfrac1{x^2},\ldots,\;$ etc, cancels out and the answer appears.

Note: - the cancellation takes place due to the odd degrees in the taylor's series.

Finally, we get the answer as $\,0\,$.